# Version Numbers Don't Show Up Properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

What I'm trying to achieve is to show a label in my about dialog which displays the version number of the application but they don't show up properly. If I have my Major and Minor Version Numbers set to 1 and 5 respectively, the label still shows 1.0 . This is the code i'm using on the Load event:

```
Label3.Text = My.Application.Info.Version.Major.ToString() + "." + My.Application.Info.Version.Minor.ToString() + "." + My.Application.Info.Version.Build.ToString()
```

I know that hard-coding a version number isn't hard but I don't want to manually update it as automation is cool.

Comment: What happens if you use just _My.Application.Info.Version.ToString()_

Comment: @Steve I still just get 1.0.0.0

Comment: But where do you set the Version information?

Comment: @Steve In the application properties

Comment: Under `Publish` or under `Application > Assembly Information...`? If the latter like it should be, did you change Assembly version, File version or both?

Comment: You'll get the version number of the Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().  Normally the EXE project in your solution, certainly what you'd want.  Crystal ball says that you put your AboutBox code in a class library project and you are modifying the version number of *that* project, not the EXE project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
Dim ver As string = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

and just check properties of `Version`

```
ver.Build
ver.Major
ver.MajorRevision
ver.Revision
ver.MinorRevision
```

In any case, you should show here how you set your version. May be you did that wrong